# How to flatten out a dataframe into 1 line and change the columns so that the columns are: "column1.index1", "column1.index2", etc?"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use a For Loop and the pd.read_html function in order to scrape tables.

Each html has 17 tables.

I start out by pulling tickers out of an excel file and turning them into a list. Then I run them through:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Jacob/Downloads/CEF Tickers.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

tickers_list = df['Ticker'].tolist()

# There are some test tickers: ["ASA", "FAX", "IAF"]

df_list1 = []

for ticker in tickers_list:
    df_list1.append(pd.read_html(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}', header=0)[0])
```

Here I am taking the first dataframe from each pd.html table scrape. There are 17 tables that actually get pulled. My plan is to have:

```
df_list1 = []
df_list2 = []
...
df_list17 = []

for ticker in tickers_list:
    df_list1.append(pd.read_html(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}', header=0)[0])
    df_list2.append(pd.read_html(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}', header=0)[1])
    ...
    df_list17.append(pd.read_html(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}', header=0)[16])
```

The dataframes in df_list1 look like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CXYf0rM0fzpIgZbLGxYQBsNzCNi18eLcyBvORChC3qE/edit?usp=sharing).

I've been searching and searching for ways to try and convert the dataframes in df_list1 into [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1afR4_cMSYt5_PCAZsUWCEbngd8HW9NwGaj4YWd-cztw/edit?usp=sharing) but to no avail.

When the dataframes in df_list1 look like that, then I can use pd.concat and take the list and turn it into one massive dataframe. Then join all the df_list1 through df_list17 together having the tickers be the index.

I've used the pd.json_normalize function before to flatten out datasets like this. Would I need to turn each dataframe into a dictionary and do the same thing?

Thank you for your time everyone.

Comment: Do you mean you want to stack the data frame?

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of the "pd.json_normalize" function where it puts the whole dictionary into 1 row. I'm looking at the docs now for pd.stack. So, yeah, stack would be a way to do this and have a multi index. I was hoping the end result would just be 1 ticker as the index with like maybe 100 columns of data which would make it easier for non-coding people to interact with the data. I really appreciate your response though. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using a dictionary instead of list, this way I can keep track of my tickers in a concatenated dataframe then reshape (flatten):

```
tickers_list = ["ASA", "FAX", "IAF"]

df_list1 = {}

for ticker in tickers_list:
    df_list1[ticker]= pd.read_html(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}', header=0)[0]
    

df_out = pd.concat(df_list1, keys=df_list1.keys())
df_out = df_out.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'Prices'})
df_out = df_out.set_index('Prices', append=1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).unstack()

df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('_'.join)
df_out
```

Output:

```
  SharePrice_52 Wk Avg SharePrice_52 Wk High SharePrice_52 Wk Low SharePrice_Current NAV_52 Wk Avg NAV_52 Wk High NAV_52 Wk Low NAV_Current Premium/Discount_52 Wk Avg Premium/Discount_52 Wk High Premium/Discount_52 Wk Low Premium/Discount_Current
ASA               $15.32                $25.45                $8.16             $20.80        $18.08         $27.91        $10.55      $24.55                    -15.52%                      -8.05%                    -19.86%                  -15.27%
FAX                $3.99                 $4.49                $2.60              $3.87         $4.65          $4.90         $3.98       $4.62                    -14.29%                      -9.09%                    -30.05%                  -16.23%
IAF                $4.78                 $5.62                $2.99              $4.50         $5.31          $6.11         $3.45       $5.21                    -10.20%                      -4.38%                    -14.10%                  -13.63%
```

---

```
tickers_list = ["ASA", "FAX", "IAF"]

df_list1 = {}

for ticker in tickers_list:
    df_list1[ticker]= pd.read_html(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}', header=0)[1]
    

df_out = pd.concat(df_list1, keys=df_list1.keys())
#df_out = df_out.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'Prices'})
df_out = df_out.unstack()

df_out.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out
```

Comment: Scott, thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed. I am so grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Scott, quick question: how do I interact with tables that have no headers? I was able to replicate your example for table 2. But for table 3, I keep getting: "KeyError: "None of ['Exposure'] are in the columns"". I tried using "df_out = df_out.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'Prices'})" as: df_out = df_out.rename(columns={'Total Investment Exposure': 'Exposure'}). Is there a way to work with data that has no headers? Thank you again for you response though. I really appreciated it. It helped so much.

Comment: Can you paste a list of three or four tickers that generates this problem?

Comment: I'm just using ["ASA", "FAX", "IAF"]. I'm pulling the 3rd table with headers=0.

Comment: Hrm... so the code above doesn't work?   Are you getting something different?

Comment: Your code worked perfectly on the 1st table. It was exactly what I needed. I was able to change your code for the 2nd table. The third table that pulls looks like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10VBBc5BwCsQCpIbpm2yEOT3Y6m_wmsrJJ7AGGx_CUfk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JacobSteenhuysen See coded to hand second table on the webpage.

Comment: So I've looked at what the tables were actually pulling. So the pd.read_html is pulling some of the wrong tables because the website sometimes gives the wrong table. i really appreciate your help though. thank you so much